# Split the first space and the last space in a string and limit the size of output in 3

Tags: php, regex, preg-split

Suppose I have a string:

```
ABC DEF SASF  123 (35)
```

And my expected output like:

```
Array (
     [0] => ABC
     [1] => DEF SASF  123
     [2] => (35)
)
```

I am trying to do this with `$str = preg_split("/(^\S+\s+)|\s+(?=\S+$)/",$str, 3);` But the current problem is this RegEx will replace the content in `$str[0]` and it would be like

```
Array (
     [0] => 
     [1] => DEF SASF  123
     [2] => (35)
)
```

How can I modify the RegEx to output my expected result ?

The online example: https://www.regex101.com/r/rK5lU1/2

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just split your input string according to the below regex.

```
^\S+\K\s+|\s+(?=\S+$)
```

Just match the first word and then discard it by adding [`\K`](http://www.regular-expressions.info/keep.html) next to `\S+`. Then match the following one or more spaces. `|` OR match one more spaces which was just before to the last word. `\S+` matches one or more non-space characters.

[DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/oT0vO3/1)

```
$str = "ABC DEF SASF  123 (35)";
$match = preg_split('~^\S+\K\s+|\s+(?=\S+$)~', $str);
print_r($match);
```

**Output:**

```
Array
(
    [0] => ABC
    [1] => DEF SASF  123
    [2] => (35)
)
```

Answer (score 2):

```
^(\S+)\s+|\s+(?=\S+$)
```

Try splitting by this. Sample code.

```
preg_split('/^(\S+)\s+|\s+(?=\S+$)/', 'ABC DEF SASF  123 (35)', -1, PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY | PREG_SPLIT_DELIM_CAPTURE)
```

Or just match and grab the captures instead of split.

```
^(\S+)\s+(.*?)\s+(\S+)$
```

[See demo](https://www.regex101.com/r/rK5lU1/5)

```
$re = "/^(\\S+)\\s+(.*?)\\s+(\\S+)$/";
$str = "ABC DEF SASF 123 (35)";

preg_match_all($re, $str, $matches);
```

Comment: Your code wouldn't work without those flags. Don't know why you don't even say anything about it.

Comment: The accepted answer is easier to understand and simpler than this solution IMO.

Comment: @user3571945 yup you have my consent.Anyways nthing working in learning more than 1 way :)